# Passing state through context in react gives error: TS2339: Property 'setImage' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to figure out why my state and setState function are not recognized as part of my created context. I hope someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong!

This is my context file:

```
import React, {ReactNode, useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const PlantContext = React.createContext({});

interface Props {
    children?: ReactNode
}

const PlantContextProvider = ({children, ...props}: Props) => {

    const [image, setImage] = useState<string>('')

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [])

    return <PlantContext.Provider value={{
    image, setImage
    }}>
    {children}
    </PlantContext.Provider>
}

export {PlantContext, PlantContextProvider}
```

My components are wrapped in the PlantContextProvider element in App.tsx, and this is how I am trying to use the context in a child component:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {PlantContext} from "../../../contexts/PlantContext";

function AddPlantBtn() {
    const plant = useContext(PlantContext)
    const input = document.getElementById('uploadImage') as HTMLInputElement;
    const file = input?.files![0]
    const [imageTaken, setImageTaken] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        plant.setImage(file) //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN, SETIMAGE IS MARKED RED
    }, [imageTaken]);
    
    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor='uploadImage'>
                <span className="btn btn-sm text-base-100 btn-primary m-2"><i className='material-symbols-rounded mr-2 text-base'>add_circle</i>Add plant</span>
                <input onChangeCapture={() => {setImageTaken(true)}} id='uploadImage' type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" hidden/>
            </label>
        </>
    );
}

export default AddPlantBtn;
```

Comment: What do you think `React.createContext({});` is specifying? Hint: there are no `image` or `setImage` properties specified in the default context value.

Comment: Aaah ofcourse! Thanks @Drew Reese!

Comment: But how would I pass the state in there? Because I cant initialize the state outside of a functional component

Comment: It's only the default value if the context doesn't have a provider higher in the ReactTree, but that's not why you need to specify them. You specify them so the types can be inferred. You can also specify the types explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a default* context value and type interface.

```
interface IPlantContext {
  image: string,
  setImage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
}

const PlantContext = React.createContext<IPlantContext>({
  image: '',
  setImage: () => {},
});
```

This is basically only defining the *shape* of the Context value, the types are generally inferred, though you generally need to fully quantify the React state updater function. The `PlantContextProvider` component still holds and initializes the state and value its providing.

* ***Note:** The `defaultValue` argument is **only** used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.*